# check URL rewriting code

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been working on this URL rewriting .htaccess code but some people have said that I am doing it wrong or backwards:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?(.*)p=(?!admin)(?!superadmin)((?![^&]*?edit)[^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?(.*)p=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\   ]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2?%1%3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Ultimately I want the user not to see the links with query strings but I need the query strings to still exist and be usable somehow so that I can check for values of $_GET variables.

In other words I need this:
- domain.com/index.php?p=Home to be rewritten as domain.com/Home
- domain.com/index.php?p=Bio to be rewritten as domain.com/Bio
- when a user clicks a link from the home page that points to domain.com/index.php?p=Bio they should see domain.com/Bio in the browser's url bar but I should still be able to echo $_GET['p'] and get 'Bio' when I land on the Bio page.

Make sense?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I understand your requirement but can you clarify what is purpose or intent of first `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}` line in your code?

Comment: @anubhava the first condition in my code is the one that makes sure addresses with p=admin, p=superadmin and p=*******edit will not be rewritten

Comment: ok but what is `(.*)` before `p=` capturing. Please clarify with one or two examples.

Comment: @anubhava that (.*) before p is un-necessary in my opinion but it was added as a suggestion to me by somebody else on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Small tweaks, and it should work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php\?.*(?<!\w)p=(?![^&]*(?:admin|edit))([^\s&#]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thank you for your reply - unfortunately with your code all I get is a bunch of 404 errors

Comment: That's an improvement, if you get a 404 we can see what was wrong with the rewritten url. 404 means the file doesn't exist, so it's not finding `index.php`... How is that possible? Please change the `L` to `R` for a moment, it will redirect so in the browser bar you'll be able to see what url we redirected to, and troubleshoot what might be going wrong

Comment: if I change the L to the R on the last line it simply works as if there were no rewriting rules (in other words I see all my regular urls with query strings)

Comment: So, that means it's redirecting to the right place! Excellent. Now, to make the redirection invisible, we normally change the `R` to `L`... But you say that the `L` gives you a 404. I wonder why! Do you have other code that could interfere? Did you definitely use `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` ?

Comment: I just wiped my cache and opened a new browser and deleted everything in my .htaccess file and added your entire code... now I am not getting a 404 but I am also not seeing any url rewriting take place at all, in other words I see my old links with query strings

Comment: Wait, we're trying to rewrite `domain.com/Bio` TO something with query strings (but hidden to the user). So if you are putting `domain.com/Bio ` in the browser and seeing query strings, some rewriting is happening. Is that what happens when you put `domain.com/Bio` in the browser?

Comment: the opposite! we are trying to rewrite query string urls to SEO friendly URLs but keep the functionality of the variables passed by the script... in other words I would like the user never to see query strings but I would like my site to work as it did before I started to use url rewriting to make the URLS SEO-friendly

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm talking about and I think there is a misunderstanding. SEO friendly means the user puts `domain.com/Bio` in the browser, right? So, what happens when you do that?

Comment: with your code if I put domain.com/Bio in the browser I get a 404 but if I go to old school links then no 404 but no rewriting either

Comment: maybe I misunderstand the SEO-friendly thing but I thought the point is to have shorter re-written URLs for the search engines to index. I want google to index domain.com/Bio and my visitor to see that URL but I need the $_GET values of an URL. If we just rewrite domain.com/Bio to domain.com/?p=Bio how would the rest of the query string values in my url be rewritten and not be indexed by google? my query strings are usually stuff like p=Bio&l=en&m=0 but I don't want a URL that's domain.com/Bio/en/0 for google or my user, I just want google to see and index domain.com/Bio

Comment: We are not rewriting to domain.com?p=bio but to index.php?p=bio as per your specs.

Comment: sorry I was just shortening domain.com/index.php?p=bio to domain.com/?p=bio but the rest of my statement stays the same. does it make sense? or am i confused? is this even possible to do?